# how to publish a protobuf message on redis through redis plus plus client

Tags: c++, for-loop, redis, stack, protocol-buffers

I am using [redis-protobuf](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-protobuf) library for serialization of data and I want to publish the message over Redis broker. How can I do that?.
I see PB.SET is there corresponding to SET command in redis . Is there PB.PUBLISH command corresponding to publish command of redis.

I tried PB.PUBLISH channel message command. I was expecting message getting published on channel topic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's no PB.PUBLISH method. You can use `PUBLISH` command to publish a serialized protobuf message.